# swift - sort array of custom object by optional date

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an array of custom objects. I want to sort them by `openingDate` `NSDate` property, but this property is optional and may be nil in some cases.
How can I sort the objects ascending so that nil dates are displayed in the end?
Here is what I'm using now, but it fails when nil date occurs:

```
projects.sort({
  $0.openingDate!.compare($1.openingDate!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
})
```

Comment: The suggested answer to the referenced thread should be applicable with minor modifications, i.e. use `distantFuture()` instead of `distantPast()` to make the entries without a date appear at the end.

Comment: thanks, I applied the solution and it worked :)